# Is it possible to configure a corda node to do p2p communication via outbound proxies?

Tags: kotlin, networking, tcp, corda, p2p

I read nodes communicate with each other using TCP/IP. But if the nodes are located behind a firewall or proxy server. Can we configure the node to use this proxy setting to connect to other node in node.conf or something?

Answer (score 1):

Corda Enterprise provides Corda Firewall.

You can read more on [docs](https://docs.r3.com/en/platform/corda/4.10/enterprise/node/corda-firewall-component.html) and take a look at this [blog](https://corda.net/blog/corda-firewall%E2%80%8A-%E2%80%8Acomponents-pki-deployment/).

Comment: ok, thanks Sneha. 
May I know the usage of 
networkServices.proxiedNodes.enabled = true in node.conf file?

Comment: similarly I read somewhere we could add address also like above.